# Make the search engine ignore specific keywords

Tags: php, search, keyword

I'm currently using

```
    $terms = explode(" ", $k);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";


    foreach ($terms as $each) {
        $i++;

        if ($i == 1)
            $query .= "keywords = '%$each%' ";
        else
            $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
}

    // connect
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password");
    mysql_select_db("search");

    $query = mysql_query($query);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows ($query);
    if ($numrows > 0) {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $keywords = $row['keywords'];
            $links = $row['link'];

            echo "<h2>$title</h2><p>$description</p>";

        }

    }
    else
        echo "No Search Results have been found for \"<b>$k</b>\"";

    // disconnect
    mysql_close();



?>
```

this piece of code I learned from a tutorial to begin my search engine. I'll be honest, I don't know any PHP, and understanding what's going on here has been a real struggle.

How do I manipulate this piece of code such that if I search "Swarthmore College" or "Swarthmore", Swarthmore results will show up. I need to make sure that just typing "College" or "swar" or "a" won't trigger the Swarthmore results. 
But I need common words like "University", "of", and "Chicago" to trigger together for college searches like "University of Chicago." It should also be triggered by abbreviations like "UChicago."

I'm sorry if this is a lot to ask, but I am completely lost. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your explanation is a bit confusing. In which cases do you want to trigger more results or not? What does it depend on?

Comment: I want to have the results for that specific college to trigger when the keyword is specific enough to identify only that one college. So if I have 'University of Delaware' and 'University of Chicago' in my database, I would want all 3 keywords to be necessary for a result to show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include an `elseif` clausule. The code would be:

```
if ($numrows == 1) {
    // You dont need to iterate if you want to show only unique result
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $keywords = $row['keywords'];
    $links = $row['link'];

    echo "<h2>$title</h2><p>$description</p>";
}
elseif ($numrows > 1)
    echo "More than one Search Results have been found for \"<b>$k</b>\". Please be more specific ";
else
    echo "No Search Results have been found for \"<b>$k</b>\"";
```